# converting excel(.xlsx) file to JSON

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, mongoose

I have excel sheet called sampledata.xlsx which i converted into json and console.log to print this data.

```js
server.js


var xlsx2json = require('xlsx2json')


xlsx2json(
    'sampledata.xlsx',
{
    dataStartingRow: 2,
    mapping: {
        'name': 'B',//name
        'sku': 'C',//unit price            //sku
        'quantity': 'D',//quantity
        
    }
}).then(jsonArray => { 
    // [
    //     {"col_1": "Barton LCC", "col_2": "30", "col_3": "86.69"}
    // ]
    
//console.log(jsonArray);
});
```

with the help of [this doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx2json).
What i want to do here is,in my sampledata.xlsx file i have more data like flat,address,price,etc here i already don't know which fields are present in my **excel sheet** but i want all that to be console.log.How could i do this is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## import xlsx2json from 'xlsx2json';

```
        OR
```

## const xlsx2json = require('xlsx2json');

```
const excel2json = [
(req, res, next) => {
xlsx2json(req.body.file.path)
  .then(result => result[0])
  .reduce((object, item, index) => {
     if (index === 0) {
      object.mapper = item;  // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
      return object;
     }
  const data = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
    data[object.mapper[key]] = item[key];
  });
  object.data.push(data);
    return object;
 }, { mapper: {}, data: [] })
   .then(excel => console.log(excel)) // this gives json as output
   .catch(err => next(err));
 },
];
```

Comment: In xlsx2json you need to send the path of excel where excel is located.

Comment: At the end you will get json as the output, where you can perform your task.                  Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install xlsx-to-json-lc --save
npm install xls-to-json-lc --save
```

```js
var exceltojson = require("xls-to-json-lc");
  exceltojson({
    input: "pass the input excel file here (.xls format)"
    output: "if you want output to be stored in a file"
    sheet: "sheetname",  // specific sheetname inside excel file (if you have multiple sheets)
    lowerCaseHeaders:true //to convert all excel headers to lowr case in json
  }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      //result will contain the overted json data
    }
  });
```

Comment: if you can see i have console.log(jsonArray) which gives me output as json and the file which i have has the extension of .xlsx.The code which you provided i tried and it give error of unsupported file.

Comment: var exceltojson = require("xlsx-to-json-lc"); can be required dfor .xlsx file type extension